# Handling cases where a JSON Key exists or not

Tags: java, json, rest-assured

I'm using rest-assured to test an API. I want to handle a scenario where a key might not exist

Given:

```
{
  "shop":{
     "shopId":1892929,
     "name":"bobs shop",
     "type":"grocery"
  }
}
```

...in which `type` key is sometimes not present, I am trying to handle as follows, using theJSONObject `has` method: https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has(java.lang.String)

```
//restassured code yields response, passed into a JSONObject
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);

if(jsonObj.has(jsonObj.getJSONObject("shop").getString("type"))){
             logger.info("Shop type found as: " + jsonObj.getJSONObject("shop").getString("type"));
}
```

This code block always evaluates to false even when `type` is present.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `.getString("type")` returns `grocery` in your case (https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject#getString(java.lang.String)) and `grocery` is not a key in `jsonObj`.

Comment: @pavelsaman you're right, `shop` and `type` are both keys.  So I want to check if `type` exists, and if so, get its key

Answer (score 3):

You just get `Response` object from your call and do:

```java
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Response response = RestAssured
                .get("https://mocki.io/v1/22617277-2eca-4fcf-b7e2-8c80851ef45d");
        if(response.path("shop.type") == null){
            System.out.println("key does not exist");
        }else{
            System.out.println(response.path("shop.type").toString());
        }
    }

}
```

You can have more complicated jsonpath query. For example if you treat having field with `null` value in different way than having no field at all you can use `find` in your jsonpath like I'm showing below:

```java
if(response.path("shop.find{it.getKey() == 'type'}") != null){
    System.out.print("Key exists ");
    if(response.path("shop.type") == null){
        System.out.println("but have null value");
    }else{
        System.out.println("and have not-null value");
    }
}else{
    System.out.println("Key does not exist");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Example json:**

```
{
    "priceOne": 1034,
    "priceTwo": {"new":2},
    "priceThree": 7282
}
```

**Checking the value of "new"**

```
       Response response =RestAssured.get("https://newnnnnnnn.free.beeceptor.com").
                        then().extract().response();                
       JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response.asString());
       String val = (jsonObj.getJSONObject("priceTwo").has("new")) ? response.jsonPath().getString("priceTwo.new"):"not foun";
        
        System.out.println(val);
```

Try JSONObj.hetJsonobject

As mentioned in above comment you can use response.path("shop.type") == null ? true : false also . But shop.type returns null for non existence and also for {"type": null}

Comment: I think the other factor that would drive whether to use the `JSONObject.has()` or the `Response.path()` check would be how the value is being used.  If you're doing assertions around the JSON object's shape and values, then using the JSONObject makes sense, and keeps similar code close to itself.  The `path()` check would make sense if you're getting very different JSON from the endpoint, and you can use a key to determine which path to use.

Comment: It depends on also how you're going to treat that data. In some situations having no field or having the field with null value might mean the same.

Comment: @ernie basically you can come up even with the only `path()` method. Some more advanced querying technique is being involved there. See my update.

Comment: @AlexeyR. I get you can do it using only `path()`.  My comment was saying you might pick the JSONObject approach if you're doing other things with the JSONObject as well, not just checking for the existence of a key.